# Is PHP supporting to create a stream context with HTTP/2 protocol?

Tags: php, http2

In the current PHP documentation or elsewhere, I could not find anything about HTTP protocol version 2 when creating a stream context.

Is the usage transparent, or must special features of HTTP/2 be taken into account? Does the use of HTTP/2 in the context of streams make any sense?

I am aware that CURL would handle all this for me - but I do not want to use CURL.

Here is a small example with FOPEN:

```
$context = [
    "http" => [
        "header" => [
            "Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Connection: close",
            "Upgrade-insecure-requests: 1",
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Dnt: 1",
            "Accept-language: en-us",
            "Content-type: text/html"
        ],
        "ignore_errors" => true,
        "max_recirects" => 3,
        "method" => "POST",
        "protocol_version" => 2.0,
        "timeout" => 30.0,
        "content" => ""
    ],
    "ssl" => [
        "disable_compression" => false,
        "verify_peer" => true,
        "verify_depth" => 5,
        "SNI_enabled" => true
    ]
];

$stream = stream_context_create($context);
$result = fopen(base64_decode(self::URL), "rb", false, $stream);
```